# Appending items to a DataFrame in a loop from a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 7 API responses which follow this structure:

I named the response `a`.

```
a = {
    'kind': 'youtubeAnalytics#resultTable',
    'columnHeaders': [{
        'name': 'video',
        'columnType': 'DIMENSION',
        'dataType': 'STRING'
    }, {
        'name': 'views',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'likes',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'dislikes',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'shares',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'estimatedMinutesWatched',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'subscribersGained',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'averageViewDuration',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'comments',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'cardImpressions',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'cardClicks',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }, {
        'name': 'estimatedRevenue',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'FLOAT'
    }, {
        'name': 'adImpressions',
        'columnType': 'METRIC',
        'dataType': 'INTEGER'
    }],
    'rows': [
        ['id_1', 6653, 95, 10, 12, 14913, 36, 134, 5, 42, 1, 0, 0],
        ['id_2', 1184, 18, 3, 2, 2397, 13, 121, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0],
        ['id_3', 1122, 29, 0, 10, 4464, 5, 238, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0],
        ['id_4', 1011, 5, 2, 1, 1361, 3, 80, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
        
     ]
}
```

I am trying to get a simple structure where the columns are names from the `columnHeaders` key and values are items from the `rows` key.

I tried:

```
# produce an empty df with all of the required columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[x['name'] for x in a['columnHeaders']])

# add the values in from the list
df2.loc[len(df)] = [x for x in a['rows'] # here I get an error
```

> ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Which makes sense because `len(a['rows'])` is `4`.

```
# This way I successfully add the first list as values to my df2
df2.loc[len(df)] = [x for x in a['rows'][0]]
```

Omitted some columns for visibility to show the desired structure:

```
    video   views   likes   dislikes    shares  estimatedMinutesWatched subscribersGained   averageViewDuration comments    cardImpressions cardClicks  
0   id_1    6653    95      10          12      14913                   36                  134                 5           42              1
```

My goal is to query the API 7 times and add each `list` produced in `rows` key as a values to my `df`.

Below is the API request that returns the structure mentioned above and what I tried:

```
# create an empty `df` with the desired columns

df = execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    endDate=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    dimensions='video',
 metrics='views,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,subscribersGained,averageViewDuration,comments,cardImpressions,cardClicks,estimatedRevenue,adImpressions',
    maxResults=200,
    sort='-views'
)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[x['name'] for x in  res['columnHeaders']])
```

```
print(df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [video, views, likes, dislikes, shares, estimatedMinutesWatched, subscribersGained, averageViewDuration, comments, cardImpressions, cardClicks, estimatedRevenue, adImpressions]
Index: []
```

```
# then I try to iterate 7 times and using timedelta move backwards. Not sure how to append the data to the df
for i in range(1,8):
    # add the reponse to df somehow
    execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate=(datetime.today()-timedelta(i+1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    endDate=(datetime.today()-timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    dimensions='video',
    metrics='views,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,subscribersGained,averageViewDuration,comments,cardImpressions,cardClicks,estimatedRevenue,adImpressions',
    maxResults=200,
    sort='-views'
)
```

What would be the best way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can correct this part of code:

```
# add the values in from the list
df2.loc[len(df)] = [x for x in a['rows'] # here I get an error
```

to

```
for i, b in enumerate(a['rows']):
    df2.loc[i] = b
```

so the content of `df2` is:

```
  video views likes  ... cardClicks estimatedRevenue adImpressions
0  id_1  6653    95  ...          1                0             0
1  id_2  1184    18  ...          0                0             0
2  id_3  1122    29  ...          1                0             0
3  id_4  1011     5  ...          0                0             0
[4 rows x 13 columns]
```

run your code after correcting, and waiting for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

`res` is my API response.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[x['name'] for x in  res['columnHeaders']])
df['datestamp'] = df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1) # create an empty column

for i in range(1,8):
    
    res_2 = execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate=(datetime.today()-timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    endDate=(datetime.today()-timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    dimensions='video',
    metrics='views,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,subscribersGained,averageViewDuration,comments,cardImpressions,cardClicks,estimatedRevenue,adImpressions',
    maxResults=200,
    sort='-views'
)
    df_add = pd.DataFrame(res_2['rows'],columns=[x['name'] for x in res_2['columnHeaders']])
    df_add['datestamp'] = datetime.today()-timedelta(i)
    print(df_add)
    df = df.append(df_add)
```